# Mathematics of Growth

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I wondered if anyone could help with the relevant steps for particular problem below.

Suppose for example, world population was about $679$ million in the year $1700$ and $954$ million in $1800$.

I wish to calculate the annual growth rate R using continuous compounding, between $1700 - 1800$.

I've noted that the relevant solution is:

$679 e^{100R} = 954$.

And the solution is:

$R = 3.4 \cdot 10^{-3}$

Could someone indicate how R is solved for in this instance on an annual continuous compounding basis?

Would be appreciated,

Best,

Andrew

Comment: Do you maybe mean that $954 = 697\cdot R^{100}$? Or how do you define growth rate?

Comment: @Dirk Please keep in mind we are talking about continuous compounding

Comment: Dirk has a point. While your (Andrew's) definition $R$ has nothing wrong with it (and a more meaningful answer can be derived from it), Dirk's definition of  $R$ would give a more intuitive answer, as you can directly see the growth percentage from it.

Comment: On to the question itself: My hint is to use logarithms.

Comment: @MattiP. Dirk's formula would work if we were considering population to grow in 100 steps, not continuously

Comment: Are you familiar with logarithms and their properties?

Comment: How about the fact that $R^{100} = e^{100 \ln{R}}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$R$ is obtained simply by taking logarythms, so:

$$e^{100R} = \frac{954}{679}$$

Now:

$$\ln{e^{100R}} = \ln{\frac{954}{679}}$$

Or, simplified:
$$100R = \ln{\frac{954}{679}}$$

So, finally
$$R = \frac{1}{100} \cdot \ln{\frac{954}{679}}$$

**NOTE:** The alternative expression $679R_y^{100} = 954$ was suggested in the comments. This would not consist, though, of a formula for continuous compounding. This is rather a discretization, as if we considered that the population stayed constant during the year and made a "jump" each 1st of January. We could also consider monthly jumps with $679R_m^{1200} = 954$ or daily jumps with $679R_d^{36500} = 954$. This does not really make too much sense in our case (well, it's still a decent apporixation), but this formula is used in, for example, interest rates

Comment: Thank you David, much appreciated. I understand now.